# What tools were used in late MS-DOS era for reverse engineering and patching binary executables?

Tags: ms-dos, reverse-engineering, executables

In the late MS-DOS era, what were the state of the art software tools for reverse engineering and patching binaries, i.e. .exe and .com files?

A simple list of the tools that were "state of the art", widely used, or considered excellent, and what they were used for, for DOS would suffice. However, the answer to this question might also depend on the answer to "What do you want to do with such a tool?". For this reason I have provided a concrete example with a use case, consider the following:

I have an old game I would like to run, but my DOS machine has too much RAM. The game issues a simple error: "Program too big to fit in memory". I have reason to suspect that it is indeed extended memory which is "insufficient", and not simply a lack of conventional memory which would typically be the case. This is beyond the point anyway, but this might be due to an integer overflow or similar issue. I want to find whatever code is doing this and just NOP it out, patch the binary, and see if that makes the problem go away.

I would like a tool that allows me to search for strings in memory, in particular that above-mentioned error. It would be nice if the tool could list references to the string. Obviously I would want to be able to have basic debugging functionality as well, breakpoints, watchpoints, etc.

Finally, I would like to be able to patch the .exe file and save it.

Obviously, I could use modern tools for this particular problem, such as IDA pro, on a modern system, but I would like to do it on the DOS machine, partly just to play around with such tools.

Comment: It's highly likely that your use case isn't just a simple patch.  Remember EMM386.EXE, HIMEM.SYS and QEMM, designed to squeeze every last byte out of the high-memory area so that these games would run?

Comment: "Program too big to fit in memory" strongly suggests lack of conventional memory is the problem, as it's MS-DOS and not the game, that's printing the message. A lot of MS-DOS games had very high conventional memory requirements, you probably need to adjust your configuration, like Robert Harvey suggested, to get the game to run. What game are you trying to play?

Comment: "I want to find whatever code is doing this and just NOP it out, patch the binary, and see if that makes the problem go away." - yeah, that'll work  :/ [Maximize Conventional Memory Under DOS](http://www.pcguide.com/opt/opt/ramDOS-c.html)

Comment: and should you want to share your patch, use the oldskool binary patch formats :) -- https://yurisk.info/2017/05/22/XCK-and-CRK-file-formats-for-binary-patching-in-windows/index.html

Comment: This is actually very common today, where virtual machines do all kinds of tricks with the binaries run inside.

Comment: Debug.com? Seriously, I used to use an early version of Norton Utilities to edit exe and com files.

Comment: I've seen not enough memory errors from applications where too much conventional memory was available.  Example, with later DOS versions and/or tools that were able to make a lot more of the 640K available.  Some programs would overflow and fail thinking there was not enough memory available in those cases.  Often the fix was simple to load DOS/drivers/etc low instead of high to consume MORE memory!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As others have mentioned, “Program too big to fit in memory” means that DOS can’t find a large enough memory block to fit the amount of memory that your program’s header requests. This can be either because you have too little available *conventional* memory (extended memory isn’t taken into account), or because your executable is corrupted.

To answer your question about state-of-the-art tools which people would have used in the late DOS era to debug, disassemble and patch executables, here are a few which I would recommend:

- [Sourcer](https://corexor.wordpress.com/2015/12/09/sourcer-and-windows-source/) was one of the best non-interactive disassemblers; it also included binary patching tools — so you’d disassemble your program, figure out where it needed fixing, and write a binary patch for it.
- IDA is an excellent *interactive* disassembler, and early versions were available for DOS (see [here](http://www.dcee.net/Files/Programm/Utils/)).
- Debuggers would commonly be used to explore the inner workings of a program. The best debugger is the one you’re most familiar with, so for most people that would be the debugger included in their development environment — Turbo Debugger for Borland users, CodeView for Microsoft users, the Watcom debugger etc. There was some cross-over, and Turbo Debugger in particular seemed quite popular back then. Other famous debuggers include [SoftICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoftICE) and Periscope (which was a real ICE, *i.e.* hardware-based). I tend to use [386SWAT](http://www.sudleyplace.com/swat/) nowadays; it wasn’t famous back in the late DOS days, since it was an internal Qualitas tool (used to develop the 386MAX memory manager), but it was released to the general public at the turn of the century and is very capable.
- Other useful tools include hex viewers and editors; examples include [QView](http://www.enlight.ru/qview/main.htm), BIEW, HIEW etc. (see [this list](http://www.reimagery.com/fsfd/filutil2.htm#hextools)). Some of these also include disassemblers, and executable header viewers (which would allow you to easily view the required memory in your case, and perhaps patch *that*). You could use one of these to actually patch your executable, after determining what byte sequence to look for, either in a disassembler or debugger.
- Once you’ve figured out what to patch, you might need an unpacker first — DOS executables were often compressed, so you wouldn’t be able to patch them directly. There were quite a few tools to handle this; I’d generally use UNP (see [this list](http://www.reimagery.com/fsfd/arc2.htm#exepck)).

Comment: I'm sure "_The best debugger is the one you’re most familiar with_" partly applies, but Borland's Turbo Debugger was -- if not the best -- at least the first I saw to fully leverage the power of the 386's protected mode to simplify a lot of things (breakpoint when an address or port was written to etc.)

Comment: @TripeHound I liked TD too; IIRC though SoftICE beat it by a few years with its 386 and hardware debugging support.

Comment: Although I never used it, IIRC (and it's a long time ago) SoftICE was originally (or at least had the option of) a hardware module that let you do things that couldn't be done (at least in real time) in pre-386 days. TD386 gave you _most_ of that ability in a software-only solution. Presumably SoftICE still won for certain tasks (e.g. possibly protected-mode code; possibly if reverse-engineering 386-debug-register-aware code).

Comment: @TripeHound SoftICE was always software-only (hence the name). Debuggers with hardware support were products such as Periscope, or the various Microtek MICE.

Comment: That makes sense ... somehow I'd got the notion it had (or could have) a hardware component. The grey cells aren't what they used to be!

Comment: @TripeHound indeed ;-). This is all thirty years ago now! I “remember” all this because I still use a lot of it every once in a while.

Comment: Rather than try to patch the binary on disk, which was often compressed and/or protected, another option was to write a loader. I had a generic piece of assembler code that hooked into `INT 21, AH=30` ([Get DOS Version](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah30)) and then loaded the target EXE. In most cases, after all the decompression/tamper-checks were complete, the first "real" bit of code would call this interrupt to check it was running on an acceptable version. At this point, I could "patch" the unpacked, in-memory code and all was well...

Comment: Such sweet memories, I used almost all those utilities, and abused MS-DOS debug once in a while, and especially before TD was out. It deserves a special mention ;)

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way to patch a .com file is `DEBUG`, which comes with any DOS installation.

DEBUG is partially usable for .exe files as well, but cannot reverse their relocation process, and so cannot save them once they have been relocated (If you load them as a plain binary file instead of an executable, you can, however, save them, but have limitations with debugging them).

Comment: I remember a tool which could recreate .exe relocations out of two memory dumps with different base addresses, and a little TSR which pushed the base address by 16 bytes.

Answer (score 9):

a bit off topic to your actual question but to make your game/exe whatever usable again:

1. **Too much memory**

common on MS-DOS for 32MByte and 64MByte (IIRC some versions use 32 some 64). The memory manager reports negative value of free or total memory causing this problem. To repair simply use Smart Drive and fill memory to it until only 32MByte or slightly less is left for the OS (IIRC the buffers could be incrementally increased). This work on all exe I used at the time even if 128 or 256 or 512 MByte of RAM memory was present.

In case your out of memory error is due to missing memory manager like: himem.sys or emm386/qemm386 just install it into startup (config.sys).

2. **CRT runtime error 200**

this is caused due to using old TP7 crt unit which on init use some CPU measuring loop. On fast computers it overflows and causes this error. There are 3  approaches to fix.

- use crt lib patch (not working for some packed executables) it was called `tppatch.exe`
- use `slow` commandline tool (also not 100%)
- turn off CPU/MB caches in BIOS Setup (this has 100% success rate for me)

See [this dedicated question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12111/why-did-ms-dos-applications-built-using-turbo-pascal-fail-to-start-with-a-divisi) for more details.

3. **bad startup config**

demanding MS-DOS programs where picky on the startup config you chose. Some programs need only himem.sys (to boost BASE memory) other need XMS/EMS. So if you know which one you need then configure your startup propperly. The easiest is to have startup boot menu in autoexec.bat/config.sys to select which one you want quickly.

For more info on this topic see (my startup config included:):

- [Run Turbo C++ in Freedos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46521076/2521214)

Now some additional tools you should have (the comments are opinion based!):

- [Volkov Commander](https://vvv.kiev.ua/download/) (file manager with file associations and context menus is a must)
- Hiew (txt viewer editor disassembler is a must)
- UniVBE (VESA driver for also non VESA gfx cards can enhance resolutions is amust)
- RAR,PKZIP,PKLITE,UC2,ARJ (packers/unpackers is a must especially pklite for executables)
- NEOPAINT (gfx editor)
- Derive (algebraic calculator and plotter now it is called derive for windows)
- [PV.EXE](https://studylibde.com/doc/2205125/beschreibung-zu-pv.exe-version-2.63-stand-02.05.97-w) (gfx extractor/decoder and viewer from any files) here [link to it](https://ulozto.net/file/JDkIKHHrD1Yp/pv-zip) from my old archive
- QV (quick view - multimedia viewer can play also DivX,avi,mov,fli,flc,... the best I saw ever)
- QPV (image viewer also the best of its kind I know of)
- MODPLAY,DOSAMP (sound players)
- TCPP or TP7 (borland compilers nad IDE with turbo debuger and linkers is a must for some patching)
- tppatch (CRT error patcher is a must)
- NASM (assembly compiler the best in its class)
- gmouse (genius mouse driver)
- load_sys (loader of drivers without restart during runtime is a must)
- DOS4GV (protected mode engine is a must)
- FAKECD (CDROM emulator is a must)
- MSCDEX (CDROM driver)
- UNERASE,UNDELETE
- TBAV (the best antivirus of its class)
- [EZ Drive](https://www.philscomputerlab.com/western-digital.html#),NDD,PQ8,[FHFORMAT](https://ulozto.net/file/0ciHd2nJKcOK/fhformat-zip) (HDD and FDD utilities)

There where also TCPP and TP7 disassemblers and discompilers (that recreate the source from compiled exe) but can not remember how they called.

Here is first link from Google with some of them included for download:

- [MS-DOS utilities](http://www.osdos.net/download2.htm)

Here some stuff like `mouse,gmouse` and USB drivers for w9x related to [other question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8945/6868)

- [MS-DOS (g)mouse and w9x USB stuff](https://ulozto.net/!47n25rih7UxZ/usb-mouse-w9x-zip)

Comment: s/Volcov/Volkov/. you can also add a link to https://vvv.kiev.ua/download/

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky thx I added it along wit EZ-Drive related to another QA I dealt with recently...

Comment: you still have 'c' instead of 'k'

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky ow I miss that `s/Volcov/Volkov/` of yours completely was seing only the link ... :)

Comment: @aCVn The EXE for the database software FoxPro For Windows was one example of that. Someone had to patch the EXE to get around it.

Comment: @aCVn I am more used to `runtime error 200` (instead of division by zero) caused by old CRT lib on fast machines (IIRC I never come across division by zero). So its either different error handling in pascal/C++ engine or different kind of cause...

Comment: @Spektre Runtime error 200 was division by zero.

Comment: How do you actually download pv.exe? it looks like exactly what i need, but i can't find a download link anywhere. The link provided is for what appears to be the documentation, which indicates at the end that there's a free shareware version available, but i have no idea where to actually get it from.

Comment: @Wug I can not find the exe nowhere ... this was sitting on my rescue disc for ~20Years [PV](https://ulozto.net/file/JDkIKHHrD1Yp/pv-zip) ... Also I do not think it was downloaded (at that time there was no Internet access nearby) most likely it was on some CD inside some PC IT magazine but do not remember which and when

Comment: @user Yes you're right I checked it and its division by zero for TC/TCPP however I am sure I was also seeing Runtime error 200 with CRT but it might be on TP (Pascal) as I coded heavily in it before C/C++ ... but it might be also because I used much much slower machines at the time I encountered this error and on fast machines its behaves differently... however is also possible my memory plays tricks on me and the error is related to something else

Answer (score 7):

The state of the art in assembly-level debugging of DOS programs is almost certainly [SoftICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoftICE).  I've never used it, but my understanding is that it was for a very long time the tool of choice of software copyright protection scheme crackers, as well as low-level operating system/device driver developers.

That said, it may well be overkill for your problem.  You do not specify how you have determined that the problem is not a shortage of conventional memory, but it should be noted that the error you quote is IIRC the standard error used by MSDOS when there is not enough conventional memory for the size specified in the [.EXE file ("MZ") header](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/exe/).  I would begin by opening the .EXE file in a hex editor and calculating:

- code_size = 512*(word at 0x0004)
- bss_size = 16*(word at 0x000A)
- total_size = code_size + bss_size

and comparing that against your available memory (as reported by mem, if you're on DOS 4+).  If it's larger (or even quite close), you may well not have enough conventional memory, even if you seem to have quite a lot.  I've seen programs before that required very nearly *all* of the conventional memory on a 640K system to load.  You may have one of these - or, as suggested by Anonymous above, you may have a corrupt file that has nonsense in one of these fields.

Comment: I broke hundreds of software protection routines with Turbo Debugger.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - it's a pretty good system, but as I understand it, SoftIce is able to debug generic protected mode apps, which I believe TD can only do if they use the same DPMI interface that Borland used for their compilers.  I believe it can also relocate itself almost entirely out of conventional memory, which can be helpful for those applications that are very close to memory limits.

Comment: "code_size = 512*(word at 0x0004)" To get the process image size you need to subtract the header size from this value. It is given in another word value, in the unit of paragraphs (16 bytes each).

Answer (score 2):

> I have an old game I would like to run, but my DOS machine has too much RAM.

The most proper way to run DOS applications in Windows is using DOSbox.

> "Program too big to fit in memory"

It may happen that you have corrupt executable.

> Obviously I would want to be able to have basic debugging functionality as well, breakpoints, watchpoints, etc.

In order to debug something, you must have an understanding of how it works. There were great disassembly tools, there was Turbo Debugger from Borland, however it is a good question if you will be able to use them properly without initial training.

Comment: DOSbox is good, and is very easy to use which is a bonus, but I'd definitely not go as far as to say it's "the most proper way".  There are compatibility issues -- specifically, it runs its own DOS version that isn't quite 100% compatible with MSDOS, and there are a few programs that misbehave because of that.

Comment: 1. Given that this is a retrocomputing forum, it's perfectly reasonable to want to run DOS and DOS programs directly on (presumably older) hardware, rather than using some form of emulation. 2. Your comment re "use them properly without initial training" isn't really relevant. I would stick to just mentioning the tools and perhaps noting if they're difficult to use for experienced reverse engineers. Most readers here already have an idea of how much they know about doing reverse engineering, and the way the OP wrote his question indicates that he's not completely clueless on this front.