# A fatal exception 0E has occurred at 0028:FF02847B Installing Windows 98 SE

Tags: windows-98

I get A fatal exception 0E has occurred at 0028:FF02847B after trying to install windows 98 se on an hp pavilion zt3000. It does this right after is says searching for plug and play hardware.

Comment: Can you successfully install and boot DOS from the HD?

Comment: @BrianH no but I can boot from dos from the cd rom

Comment: I'd recommend you try to install DOS on HD and include those results in your question.

Comment: @BrianH when I try to install dos when I burn the second setup disk and try to move to the second disk it doesn't recognize the cd rom.

Comment: How much RAM is in this device?

Answer (score 4):

I would try to install from HDD or from USB Key (if your BIOS allows it) because CD-ROMs are often buggy on older laptops after few years and Win 9x  is really sensitive to such things.

So you need a MS-DOS bootable drive with FAT32 or FAT16 with all the Win9x installation files on it (~115MByte for W98SE).

So Boot to MS-DOS and run setup....

To install MS-DOS on a HDD you just:

1. **use `fdisk` or any partition manager**

   to create drive with FAT32 or FAT16 (FAT32 is better for Win98). Beware you can lose data on the HDD drive if you repartition already partitioned drive... For USB key use **HP USB Disk Storage FormatTool**. If you already have FAT drive than this step is not needed. To make your drive boot-able its partition must be active or some boot-manager must be used instead (like lilo boot or BIOS boot menu)
2. **format**

   Format your drive (probably `C:`) with

   ```
   FORMAT C: /S
   ```

   that will format drive C with FAT32 or FAT16 depending on which MS-DOS version you got. And also it will copy system files so it will be boot-able with MS-DOS. The USB utility do this on its own... In case you just want to install MS-DOS on existing FAT drive then use SYS command instead of FORMAT.
3. **transfer w98 files**

   either use `COPY` command or some file manager like `NC,VC,FAR`.

So now just boot to MS-DOS from your drive and run w9x setup using

```
CD c:\w98_install_path
setup.exe
```

For more info see:

- [How do I create a boot menu to select between Windows and DOS?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6814/6868)

btw If this does not help try to install with disabled CPU caches and or limited CPUID in BIOS ...

In case your HDD is SCSI,SATA,AHCI you need specific drivers from the manufactor on a FDD drive !!!

Comment: +1 for installing from hard drive. This is what I _always_ did, I copied the whole software to C:\SOFTWARE or C:\WIN\SETUP, and installed from there. It also made it much easier to subsequently install drivers.

Comment: @KlaymenDK oh yes when Win 9x was installed from CD it always annoyingly ask for CD and/or  floppy while searching drivers ... if installed from HDD and keeping the installation folder intact the problem disappears...

Comment: Another ++ for install from HD - I would always do that as well from Win95 and Win98. I even hacked some additional Intel INFs into the first-stage CABs, greatly improving initial hardware compatibility.
People didn't seem to mind the wasted space, even in some cases where techs would copy the entire Win95 CD - including the bonus video clips :)

Answer (score 2):

Between then and now, quite a bit of new extensions have been built into standard PC technology that Windows 98 wasn't even been thinking of. Depending on your possible BIOS setup, your mileage for success might vary:

The first thing I would try is *disable ACPI completely* - This has always been a problem with Win98.

You might also need to disable APM (Advanced Power Management)

Then disable all "enhanced parallel port" support and make that plain and dumb, do the same for all other devices.

Upgrade the BIOS to the newest version

Comment: I checked the and it doesn't have any of those settings in the bios even after updating. Only thing similar is parallel port mode and there isn't an off option.

Comment: What BIOS type and version do you have?  Most screenshots I can see of ZT3000s have AMI BIOS v02.xx, and the [manual for that BIOS setup](https://ami.com/ami_downloads/AMIBIOS8_EZ-Port_Users_Guide.pdf) definitely shows an ACPI tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try running memtest86. Also upgrade your BIOS if there's one available for your motherboard. And disconnect/remove anything you don't need to install Windows 98.