# Logitech drivers from Windows 95 Installer on the actual disk

Tags: windows-95, mouse

I'm attempting something that might seem crazy but I got stuck at the end. I am installing Windows 95, on a flash drive, using a PC with modern hardware (Not a virtual machine!). I got around the memory issue (16GB > 1GB) with `MaxPhysPage` and the `Windows protection error` issue (4.0GHz > 2.1GHz) with `CPU95FIX`. I can boot into Windows 95, the basic things work (keyboard and screen at really low resolution), but the mouse... It is recognized as a mouse but even a single tiny movement can make it teleport everywhere, randomly click at random places and drag from random places to random places.

At first, the installer also had this issue but the installer has a flag for it. `SETUP /iL` makes the installer load the Logitech mouse drivers instead of the normal mouse drivers and that seemed to fix the mouse for the setup. However, I couldn't figure out how to load these drivers on the actual installation so the mouse works normally there. If there is a file inside the installation CD, what's the path to it? If the installation already has the driver, how can I activate it? If there is a 3rd party driver I need to install, where can I get it from?

The mouse is a wireless Logitech M705 connected via Logitech's USB dongle. The same dongle is also connected to the keyboard. I am yet to figure out how it works at all but it works and I'm not going to question it.

Comment: Probably `autoexec.bat`; I don't know what the driver's called, but if you find out and it works please post an answer.

Comment: Did you try installing Logitech Mouseware? Can be had from here: http://www.medical-online.com/mware.html

Comment: back in the days we used mostly the `gmouse.com` (genius) for all the mouses that was making a fuss. Do you have USB legacy support  enabled in BIOS ? The USB dongle is connected to USB 2.0 I hope ... the 3.0 ports are not reliable for old HW or SW...

Comment: @Spektre Yes, I do have it enabled. Also I had it connected to USB 3.0 during the setup and the mouse worked flawlessly with the setup drivers.

Comment: some crazy gaming mouses have a switch for sensitivity modes  may be your setting is just too high (usually some click pattern can change it) but I do not use such mouses so I can not help there if the case ... they are teleporting like you sad even on new OS from mine point of view too. In case of need for mouse durring install you can temporarily use keyboard mouse left ATL + left shift + num lock ...

Comment: also  there where USB 2.0 drivers for w9x packages including some mass storage and mouses and keyboard drivers from VIA I think ... VIA USB V2.44 or something like that

Comment: @Spektre It's a common wireless USB mouse by Logitech, not a gaming mouse.

Comment: @Spektre Sensitivity shouldn't make it randomly click at places. Also it doesn't even move to the direction I move the mouse.

Comment: that sounds like different protocol but that would make sense only if the dongle is emulating RS232 or PS2. From genius mouses the mouse packets had changed a bit they added 1 byte (and latter on mouses even more) that is why the `gmouse.com` driver usually solved any issues as it could decode the newer formats correctly (even for different vendor mouses). try to add it in autoexec.bat

Comment: @Spektre The mouse is detected as a PS/2 Mouse, I should have mentioned that... Could you provide a link to GMOUSE? And does it work with Windows 95?

Comment: @pixelomer I poked my old archives and I put the stuff in [here](https://ulozto.net/!47n25rih7UxZ/usb-mouse-w9x-zip) there is old mouse and the gmouse I mentioned, my old autoexec and config , the USB driver I mentioned some lost DLL for games and USB mass storage drivers ... (just chose a slow download so you do not need to register)

Comment: @pixelomer also IIRC the gmouse.com had some switches too try `/?` or `-h` or `/h` to see them all ... but I have absolutely no experience with wireless stuff ... try first to get the gmouse work in MS-DOS (for example in volkov commander) ... IIRC w9x windows preserves MS-DOS drivers loaded before windows start (or at least some of them) if you disect my autoexec and config you will see I mix them a lot. I added the links in here [How to patch binaries in DOS?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/how-to-patch-binaries-in-dos/6256#6256)

Comment: @pixelomer of coarse there is high risk that your BIOS does not recognize your dongle as PS2 and the PS2 is just emulated on windows drivers side in such case the gmouse will probably not work ... try the VIA USB drivers too ... they solve a lot of issues ...

Comment: @Spektre GMOUSE.COM works brilliantly in DOS mode (I tested it with `EDIT.COM`) but I couldn't find a way to load it in Windows mode. When I put it into CONFIG.SYS, I get some really weird graphics. When I put it into SYSTEM.INI, the system starts and immediately shows "It's now safe to turn off your computer".

Comment: @pixelomer then try to install genius PS2 mouse driver ... I think they should be a part of the w95osr2 installation you just need to select it manually.

Comment: @Spektre Are you sure? I can't find it in the New Hardware Wizard...

Comment: @pixelomer I am not sure but I would expect it should be there ... choosing vendor first ... but It might be also w98 instead ... haven't work in w9x for years. IIRC genius still provides w9x drivers for PS2 mouses try to find one that works (for older models)

Comment: @pixelomer btw in the hardware wizard you had to click something to show all the drivers available in installation they where not visible directly ...

Comment: @Spektre I dis click that, it didn't show up in any of the vendors.

Comment: which w95 you got the original or SR2 ? but in you case I would try to seach for the PS2 mouse driver (no USB or wireless only PS2) and try which one works ... IIRC it does not need to be the same vendor like on USB/PCI...

Comment: Are you sure about the SETUP /iL switch? An online search shows SETUP /L instead for old Logitech mice, e.g. http://tiplord.com/misc/setupswitch.html

Comment: Huh. I think I got that switch from `setup /?`, I will try that switch.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 95 Setup and Windows 95 will probably be using different types of drivers. Setup runs direct from DOS, so will use real-mode drivers, whereas Windows 95 will prefer virtual device drivers (for the CPU's "virtual mode" ), to avoid having to switch to and from real mode every time it talks to the mouse. It can use real-mode drivers if necessary, but Windows 95 includes VMOUSE.VXD which works with most mice (except yours).

On a modern system, the speed penalty from a real-mode driver won't be an issue. If you can load a real-mode mouse driver in DOS (through CONFIG.SYS and AUTOEXEC.BAT) before Windows boots, Windows should use the real-mode driver instead. If you can't fish the real-mode driver out of the Windows 95 CD, you could try one of the drivers listed [here](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/util_e.html).

Comment: Incidentally, Setup from Windows 95 is running under Windows 3.1.